# Wordpress Tax Query Not Working?

Tags: wordpress, loops, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, args

Can anyone please advise why the following WP query is not working?

```
           <?php if (is_page(10)) {
                $taxTerm = "restaurants";
            } elseif (is_page(12)) {
                $taxTerm = "offices";
            } elseif (is_page(14)) {
                $taxTerm = "hotels";
            } elseif (is_page(16)) {
                $taxTerm = "flowers";
            } elseif (is_page(18)) {
                $taxTerm = "green-walls";
            }

                    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'gallery_items',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'industries',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $taxTerm,
                        ),
                    ),
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'orderby'   => 'title',
                    'posts_per_page' => '5',
                    );
```

It doesnt seem to like the tax_query? although this coding matches what is on the codex?

Comment: What about this isn't working? Please go into a little more detail about the posts that you've got, and what is supposed to be the result of the filter. Also post what you've tried so far in order to get your expected result

Comment: It doesn't pull through anything? The tax_query isn't working, it should filter my gallery by the taxonomy term.

Comment: What does `$q = new WP_Query($args); var_dump($q->get_posts());` yield? Consider adding the code where you registered your custom posts & taxonomies, for context.

Comment: `$taxTerm` is probably not a string. I bet you're accidentally sending an array instead of string - double check that.

Comment: its returning " array(0) { } "  ???

Comment: @staypuftman, ive updated my post to show how I have set my $taxTerm

Comment: @staypuftman, even if I hardcode the terms, the tax_query still doesn't work?

Comment: Resolved, taxonomy name was wrong :/

Comment: @heady12 - no worries, I've done the same thing many times. Another gotcha is when you use `get_terms()` to display all your terms - make sure you set the `'hide_empty' => 0` parameter in the arguments.